# How to display a list of users on line asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a chat side bar that I would like to populate dynamically from the identity users. The below script will display my name 5 times but I would like the list of users online to be displayed through this function.

```
//creates markup for a new popup. Adds the id to popups array.
    function populatesidebar() {
        var sidebarNameHtml = '';
        for (var iii = 0; iii < 5; iii++) {
            sidebarNameHtml = sidebarNameHtml +'<div class="sidebar-name"><a href="javascript:register_popup(\'Jodaine2\', \'Jodaine2\');"><img width="30" height="30" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Jodaine.PNG")"/><span>Jodaine</span></a></div>';
        }
        $('.chat-sidebar').html(sidebarNameHtml);
    }
```

I am using the registration system comes with the project when selecting single user authentication. To get the user through to the html I used

```
using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {

            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }
```

But I would like to manage the users through the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the model in view, something like:

@model List<WebApplication1.Models.User>

Then you need to write some javascript dynamically. Something like:

```
    function populatesidebar() {
        var sidebarNameHtml = '';
        @foreach (WebApplication1.Models.User user in Model)
        {
            @: sidebarNameHtml = sidebarNameHtml +'<div class="sidebar-name"><a href="javascript:register_popup(\'@user.FName\', \'@user.LName\');"><img width="30" height="30" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Jodaine.PNG")"/><span>Jodaine</span></a></div>';
        }
        $('.chat-sidebar').html(sidebarNameHtml);
    }
```

Some of this is static but there is some razor that loops through your model inserting some User properties into the javascript. You were trying to write some javascript that loops through the model. The javascript will be executed in the browser, on the client, which knows nothing of your model. You need to execute razor on the server that writes the javascript you need to the page that is sent to the browser.

Comment: So carrying out a task like this is better to use the server side? in PHP I usually use JSon to communicate between the server and client?

Comment: I wouldn't say it was better. But given your choice of tag I assumed you wanted an asp.net MVC method.

Comment: OK Thanks I have tried what you have sent but didn't work. It probably my fault so am just watching a bunch of MVC 5 Tutorials.

Comment: Well, it won't work if you litterally copy what I put. WebApplication1.Models.User is a model I tested with and your user class is unlikely to have peroperties FName and LName. You need to use the approach, which is valid.

Comment: OK, so what didn't work? When you examined the script in the browser was it not what you expected or is there an error in javascript?

Comment: I got this error message: 

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_y4hs0zrp.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I suggest you step through your code with the debugger to locate the line on which the offending reference is. Once you have identified the line set a breakpoint on that line and restart. When execution stops at that line examine all the C# object and property references to see which is null.

Comment: It works now thanks(Only in Account/Index). The problem was I had it in _Layout.cshtml which is where I need it. but the functionality am looking for works. Cheers.